# Memory usage blows up when iterating over array

Tags: memory-management, julia

I'm working on a Jacobi solver for the Poisson equation using Julia. The solver is called iteratively until `err` is sufficiently small (~1e-8), which takes around 25,000 loops through the function for my `nx = ny = 80` test case. Profiling shows that most of the time is spent in the inner loop (as expected), but memory allocation seems to be running away--the @time macro gives 38 gigabytes allocated in order to reach convergence, which seems way too much since I don't think I'm creating new arrays for each loop.

```
function jacobi(P::Array{Float64,2}, maxiter::Int64)
    P_old = copy(P)
    for j = 2:ny-1
        # Main body loop
        for i = 2:nx-1 
             @inbounds P[i,j] = ((P_old[i+1,j] + P_old[i-1,j])*dx2 
                               + (P_old[i,j+1] + P_old[i,j-1])*dy2)/denom-Rmod[i,j]
        end
    end
    err = vecnorm(P::Array{Float64,2}-P_old::Array{Float64,2})/sqrt(nx+ny)
    return (P, err)
end
```

I've timed the function for 1000 loops, calling from a function wrapper (`methodwrap`) that sets initial conditions:

```
function methodwrap(solver, maxiter::Int64) # (solver fn name, max # of iterations)
    P = copy(P0)
    iter = 1
    err  = 1.0
    maxerr = 1e-8
    prog = Progress(maxiter,.2, "Solving using $solver method", 10) # Show progress bar
    while (err > maxerr) && (iter < maxiter)
        P, err = solver(P, maxiter)
        next!(prog) # Iterates progress bar counter
        iter += 1
    end
    println()
    return (P, iter, err)
end
```

Contrary to my wishes, it looks like memory allocation scales with the number of loops, so I'm doing something wrong. It looks as if approximately 1.4 mb is allocated with each Jacobi pass:

```
julia> @time methodwrap(jacobi,1000)
Solving using jacobi method 98%|##########|  ETA: 0:00:00
elapsed time: 4.001988593 seconds (1386549012 bytes allocated, 26.45% gc time)
```

I've tried reducing the inner loop arrays to vector subarrays and using @simd:

```
function jacobi2(P::Array{Float64,2}, maxiter::Int64)
    P_old = copy(P)::Array{Float64,2}
    for j = 2:ny-1
        # Main body loop
        Pojm = sub(P_old,:,j-1)
        Poj = sub(P_old,:,j)
        Pojp = sub(P_old,:,j+1)
        Pj = sub(P,:,j)
        Rmodj = sub(Rmod,:,j)
        @simd for i = 2:nx-1 
             @inbounds Pj[i] = ((Poj[i+1] + Poj[i-1])*dx2
                              + (Pojp[i] + Pojm[i])*dy2)/denom-Rmodj[i]
        end
    end
    err = vecnorm(P::Array{Float64,2}-P_old::Array{Float64,2})/sqrt(nx+ny)
    return (P, err)
end
```

However, this only seems to increase memory allocation and decrease speed, and I get a @simd warning:

```
julia> @time methodwrap(jacobi2,1000);
Warning: could not attach metadata for @simd loop.
Solving using jacobi2 method: 100%|##########|  ETA: 0:00:00
elapsed time: 4.947097666 seconds (1455818184 bytes allocated, 29.85% gc time)
```

This is my first project in Julia, so I'm probably making a really obvious mistake, but I haven't found a solution yet. I've defined global vars as constants. I've gone through the performance tips several times, I've linted the file, I've used TypeCheck to make sure my types are consistent, and everything looks fairly kosher to my eyes. What am I doing wrong? I've posted my [full code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b322b44f3a8e3ee45fc) on Gist if you'd like to check that as well.

Comment: Try running with memory allocation tracking: `julia --track-allocation=user yourscript.jl`. It should tell you which lines are doing all the memory allocation.

Comment: Can you post how to create **P0**?

Comment: @waTeim: The P0 creation script is included in the full code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b322b44f3a8e3ee45fc

Comment: @Iain: how do I 'view the resulting `*.mem` files'?

Comment: They are just normal text files, your source files in fact, with the memory allocated for each line next to it.

Comment: @Iain: Sorry, should have been more specific--where do I find the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the problem was subtle.  I made 3 changes (see below).  I did use as @IainDunning suggested --track-allocation=user which pointed to the questionable line.  Both of these problems come from using global variables.

After these changes

```
julia> @time methodwrap(jacobi,1000)
elapsed time: 0.481986712 seconds (116650236 bytes allocated)
```

#### change 1 add const to nx and ny

You had const everywhere except for these 2 variables but when left non const and global that cause the loop iterator *i* to allocate unnecessarily.

```
nx=80 # Number of mesh points in the x-direction
ny=80 # Number of mesh points in the y-direction
```

was changed to

```
const nx=80 # Number of mesh points in the x-direction
const ny=80 # Number of mesh points in the y-direction
```

#### change 2: avoid Rmod of type Array{Any,2}

```
const Rmod = dx2*dy2*R/(2*(dx2+dy2))
```

was changed to

```
const Rmod = convert(Array{Float64,2},dx2*dy2*R/(2*(dx2+dy2)))
```

Comment: What file/dir does `--track-allocation=user` output to? It isn't in  the directory where I ran the command.

Comment: @AlexAmes It may be the way we invoked the program.  Could you provide a few details on your install/OS?

Comment: It should be in the source folder; i.e., if your package has a file in `src/mypackage.jl`, there will be a file `mypackage.jl.mem` in the same `src` folder.

Comment: @waTeim Hi, could you tell me why "change2" works for you ? I mean, what is wrong with the first version.`const Rmod = dx2*dy2*R/(2*(dx2+dy2))`. ?